# Unable to update "old" files via Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm unable to update files via Drive API since server build:

Server HTTP Upload Server Built on May 15 2014 11:06:48 (1400177208)

Uploading new data to update an existing file always results in a HTTP error:

```
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 180
< Date: Mon, 19 May 2014 12:26:54 GMT
* Server HTTP Upload Server Built on May 15 2014 11:06:48 (1400177208) is not blacklisted
< Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on May 15 2014 11:06:48 (1400177208)
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
```

Response: (500) Internal Error

But creating a new file via drive UI and upload (via update) the same data to the new drive file (**I only change the file ID in my script**) works.

So I don't think its an error in my script, because:

- Downloading works
- Listing works
- Uploading with new files works
- Uploading to my old works well till May 15 2014 11:06:48 the new server build

FYI: I noticed that my old files served from docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export... and new files www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/...

Update May 20. 2014: Drive UI shows "Add-ons" in menu only for new created spreadsheet files. In my old spreadsheets "Add-ons" are missing.

Comment: It seems that files that use old format of Google Spreadsheet can't be updated via the API, while the [new ones](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/new-google-sheets-faster-more-powerful.html) are good.

Comment: How were you updating the file? Can you provide some sample code in your question?

Comment: @EricKoleda I just stopped using the old files and only using new files.